# iOS change container view height dynamically

Tags: ios6, container-view

How can one change the height of the container view dynamically depending on the amount of images of its childView?

[image: container]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a view like any other view, so you change it in the same way. You'll need to arrange to get a reference to it. When you set things up in the storyboard like this, you get an extra level of hierarchy that you wouldn't get if you created the parent-child view-controller architecture by hand (in code): there is a container view and inside that is the child view controller's view, whereas if you do it in code, there is *no* container view - the child view controller's view is all there is.

Comment: @matt Could you please elaborate on the actual answer to this? How does one go about adjusting the size of the container view, when the Embedded View Controller's contents change? Thank you.